# How to avoid someone concurrently working on same task and wasting everyone's time

Tags: colleagues, coworking

I am working with another developer. I was originally assigned to one problem, and he decided to do a rewrite of my work because requirements changed during and after testing.

I am unsure how to proceed in this situation because clearly there was a gap in communicating requirements as they were changing. Secondly, I could have done the re-write myself.

1. I wasted time working on the problem with the wrong requirements (changing requirements were not communicated to me)
2. it seems he decided to not trust my judgement and work. It seems he just assumed that he was the only one who could do it, or I couldn't do it; and now, I can't prove otherwise.

I don't want to create a pattern where this developer or others don't talk to me about what they want, and just assume that I can't do something (because that's what this seems to stem from, or maybe I am just being insecure). How can I avoid this in the future, or is this even a big deal to being with?

Comment: `It seems he just assumed` are you sure this wasn't an order from above? Do you have any team leader that communicates the changes to others?

Comment: I am not sure, but it's unlikely. We are working pretty independently.

Comment: Did you ask your (mutual) boss about this?

Comment: Don't worry, the requirements will soon change again. Then you just rewrite the code your way, without telling him.

Comment: Are you sure he wasn't assigned to do the rewrite of the work after the requirements changed? How did he know of the changing requirements but not you?

Comment: Are you co-located? Who is in charge of changing the scope? What does that process of change look like? Did someone try to tell you about the change initially? Is there an issue tracker or some project management software being used to track features and the work in progress? It's not the end of the world, but this issue of communication does need to be fixed at some point.

Answer (score 1):

If there was a problem communicating the requirements to you originally, I doubt the process is any better now that they've decided to change them.

Sometimes it's just easier to do something yourself than explain it to someone else. Communication requires a certain amount of effort from both sides. If they don't tell you anything, it's not your fault.

Ask about the quality of your original code. It's possible there was something he didn't like about it, but you never know. Maybe he felt bad for giving you bad specs and making you do it all over again? I know I would if it was my fault.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems he decided to not trust my judgment and work. It seems he just assumed that he was the only one who could do it, or I couldn't do it; and now, I can't prove otherwise.

This is a big assumption. Lots of the time, people work on issues simply because they see it needs to get done, they know how to do it, they need something to work on, or they incorrectly think they are responsible for it. Sometimes your code can be your baby and it feels like a personal insult if people cast doubt on the quality of your baby

Make a decision about who you want to do it, send an email to the other person and copy your manager.

> Jim, thanks for getting started on the rewrite in light of the change of scope. I was a bit late in getting the message about the new requirements and I would really prefer to pick up from here if that's alright with you. Otherwise, I need to get working on something else.

Or the alternative:

> Jim, thanks for getting started on the rewrite in light of the change of scope. I was a bit late in getting the message about the new requirements, but it looks like you've already made some good progress. If you want to take it from here, just let me know if you want me to go over my initial design. I'll shift to start working on X.

You've framed the situation so that it is clear that the problem here was a change in requirements, not a quality problem on your code. Your manager now knows the plan and you now no longer have to be partially responsible for the project. If Jim is doing the rewrite, he is responsible. Also, now it is clear that Jim doing the rewrite is not Jim sacrificially bailing you out of a disaster.

If your code really was bad, now they are responsible for telling you, "No. We have a problem with your code. It was really bad." Then you can say that you would like to review it with them so that they can show you the specific ways that it needed improvement.